# .htaccess To Different Files Depending On Inputed URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a profile page and a edit profile page. The profile page is working pretty well, and the URLs are stored in a database. It works like this:

1. The user enters the URL (`localhost/postin'/profiles/username`)
2. Once the URL is inputted the `.htaccess` file redirects to the `profile.php` file where it shows the profile information

The above works very well, and the .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

What happens though when I **localhost/postin'/profiles/edit/username**? It does not work with my current `.htaccess` because it thinks edit is part of the username, when really it is just another file. I tried this for a `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^edit/([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

yet it did not seem to work! :(

So here is a quick example of what I would like it to do. The user's username is `hawkeye`. So "**hawkeye**" enters `localhost/postin'/profiles/hawkeye` to get to his profile. Then to edit his profile he enters `localhost/postin'/profiles/edit/hawkeye`.

What would the `.htaccess` file for this look like? Thank you! :)

**UPDATE**

Here is the .htaccess I am using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^edit/([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ editprofile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

and when I try the URLS **localhost/postin'/profiles/username** and **localhost/postin'/profiles/edit/username** it always goes to **localhost/postin'/profiles/username** no matter what... Any ideas? :D Thank You

**FIXED**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^edit/([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ editprofile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that in your: `localhost/postin'/profiles/.htaccess` :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^edit/([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ editprofile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Redirect `profiles/username` -> `profiles/profile.php?user=username`
Redirect `profiles/edit/username` -> `profiles/editprofile.php?user=username`

Comment: Hi, um I just started testing this, and it does not seem to work :( It goes to the profiles/username automatically, even if I input profiles/edit/username.

Comment: It does the same as the one before, it will just execute RewriteRule ^([\w.'@\\\/-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L], it only seems to be going to profile.php, and not edit.php

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong :( It is still only executing to profile.php, even when I enter profiles/edit/username.

Comment: You don't use an other .htaccess ? (root postin' or edit folder ?)

Comment: Nope only 1 .htaccess

Comment: You are sure it's not `editprofile.php` because you can't see the page name (and like you change the name...) ?

Comment: Yes but the content of the file  `editprofile.php` is correct (not the same as `profile.php`). Because it must work!

Comment: Ok thank you! :) I will keep testing it, I must be doing something wrong! xD